# C# string to Cstring

Tags: c#, c, string

I have a C function compiled in a dll. The fonction called HelloYou is written like this:

```
const char* HelloYou(const char*)
{
    char retval[128];

    if (strlen(name) > 120)
        return "Hello too long named guy";

    sprintf(retval, "Hello %s", name );
    return retval;
}
```

Now, what I want is to call that function with C#... Let's say with the argument has the "Stack Overflow".

I have successfully called a function in the dll called HelloWorld that returns a const char*

Comment: Don't return a pointer allocated on the stack! It will become invalid when the function returns. (Or maybe C# takes care of this, but at least in just-C it is Undefined Behaviour)

Comment: @Kninnug Thank you! Solved my issue. Please post has an answer so that I can select it has the good one!